# Getting the next/previous 'photo page' from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

While there are functions like:

```
get_next_post();
next_image_link();
```

none of these can be used to help provide forwards and backwards links for photo pages in a blog. I know I can access the next photo in line because wordpress has the following in it's `header.php`

```
<!-- RSS & Pingbacks -->
...
<link rel='index' title='HugoPip' href='http://www.something.com' />
<link rel='start' title='Hello world!' href='http://www.something.com/?p=1' />
<link rel='prev' title='Driving Like a BOSS' href='http://www.something.com/?photo=driving-like-a-boss' />
<link rel='next' title='MegaCuts' href='http://www.something.com/?photo=megacuts' />
```

these are declared somewhere in `wp-include/default-filters.php` from what I can make out. I just don't know how to access them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:

```
<?php previous_post('%','&laquo; previous','no'); ?> / <?php next_post('%','next &raquo;','no'); ?>
```